# Folder navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7

I recent intrested at skydrive api and I have problem with folder navigation. I resolve with 2lvl depth but with deeper I have problem. I was thinking about get all folderID and stroe it in string[][], but there has to be more gently. Could you suggest something?

Comment: Could you, maybe, show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Tree like object structure you need to store. You should try something like this

```
  public class Folder
    {
        public Folder(Folder parent, string folderId)
        {
            this.FolderId = folderId;
            this.Parent = parent;
        }

        public Folder Parent { get; private set; }
        public string FolderId { get; private set; }
    }
```

You can use and create them in a loop structure starting from the parent.